# Dictionary inside List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

Imagine that I have this list:

```
a=[ {"user":"John","password":"123"} , {"user":"Mike","password":"12345"} ,{"user":"Peter","password":"qwerty"}]

user=input("insert your username")
password=input("insert your password")
```

Now I want to know if the user and password typed are in the previous list, how can I solve this problem?

If I want now to have  3 scenarios: one where the user and password matches, the second where the username is correct but the password is incorrect and the last one where the username does not exist.

```
if {'user':user,'password':password} in a:
    print("okay")
else:
    if {'user':user} in a and {'password':password} not in a:
        print("user okay, but incorrect pass")
    else:
        print("No username")
```

This type of code will not work, right?
So how can I solve the second step (after the first else)?

Comment: If you can change the structure of that, I recommend to work directly with dictionaries, i.e.`{'Jhon':'1234', 'Mike': '12345'}`

Comment: It is kind of an exercise, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
if {'user':user,'password':password} in a:
    # it is already in there
else:
    # it isn't in there
```

**Edit**

Use:

```
if {'user':user,'password':password} in a:
    # it is already in there
elif any(user == i['user'] and password != i['password'] for i in a):
    # user name is correct, but password isn't
else:
    # it isn't in there
```

Comment: If I want to have like 3 scenarios: one where the user and password matches, the second where the username is correct but the password is incorrect and the last one where the username does not exist.

Comment: @alladin Edited mine.

Answer (score 0):

**One way to do this :**

```
a=[ {"user":"John","password":"123"} , {"user":"Mike","password":"12345"} ,{"user":"Peter","password":"qwerty"}]

user=input("insert your username")
password=input("insert your password")

flag = True
for i in a :
    if i['user'] == user and i['password'] == password :
        print('match') # or whatever
        flag = False
        break

if flag :
    print('not there ') # or whatever
```

Comment: Hi, yeah I admit yours is simple one and more pythonic way. I didn't see your answer when I posted this. But  I think it is easily understandable even by non pythonic programmer.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can follow solution suggested by @U9-Forward or you can change your dict and instead of having list of dictionaries you can simply have a dictionary where the key = actual name and value = actual password. If you have a lot of objects in your dict and this function is going to be called very often then this solution is better in terms of time complexity.

So you initially you convert your list a to dict called `user_password_dict`

```
user_password_dict = {user_obj['user']: user_obj['password'] for user_obj in a}
```

After that you can easily check if user and corresponding password exist in your `user_password_dict` by this statement:

```
if user in user_password_dict and user_password_dict[user] == password:
    # do something here
else:
    # do something here
```